# not run expect script in ansible

Tags: shell-script, expect, ansible

my script is :

```
#!/usr/bin/expect 

set timeout 1

spawn /etc/init.d/oracleasm configure

expect "Default user to own the driver interface []:\r"
send -- "grid\r"
expect "Default group to own the driver interface []:\r"
send -- "asmadmin\r"
expect {Scan for Oracle ASM disks on boot (y/n) [y]:\r}
send -- "y\r"
interact
```

When I run normally there is no problem, But when I run with an ansible does `not apply`.

my ansible code :

```
- name: -- run oracleasm-configuration.sh (oracleasm configure -i) --
  shell: |
    /root/oracleasm-configuration.sh
```

Comment: how is `interact` going to work off on some presumably remote system?

Comment: take a look at [*sexpect*](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect) with which you can write *Expect* scripts with shell code only.